# Как сделать цикл для вывода лесенки?

Tags: python, циклы

Добрый день. Мне нужно сделать цикл для того что бы нарисовать "Лесенку"

пример:

```
print('_')

print(' |')

print('  _')

print('   |')

print('    _')

print('     |')

print('      _')

print('       |')

print('        _')

print('         |')
```

Чтобы при вызове программы получалось примерно так

> C:\Projects\SCP>python test.py

```
_
 |
  _
   |
    _
     |
      _
       |
        _
         |
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Стоит почитать справку по python. Отдал вопрос сыну-школьнику, вот код от него:

```
y=int(input("Введите число ступенек: "))
y=y*2
out=' '
x=1
while x<y+1:
    if x%2 == 0:
        print(out,"|")
    else:
        print(out,"_")
    out+=' '
    x+=1
```

Answer (score 4):

Решение с циклом **for**. Конструкция `sys.argv[1]` узнаёт, сколько требуется ступенек (прочитывает из аргументов командной строки), можно заменить на произвольное число либо на вызов `input()`.

```
for step in range(0, int(sys.argv[1])):
    print(' ' * (step * 2), '_')
    print(' ' * (step * 2 + 1), '|')
```

Answer (score 0):

Вы можете использовать вертикальную табуляцию `\v` [ссылка](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A2%D0%B0%D0%B1%D1%83%D0%BB%D1%8F%D1%86%D0%B8%D1%8F), [ссылка](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3380538/what-is-a-vertical-tab).

```py
>>> print('Hello\vworld!')
Hello
     world!
```

Код:

```py
>>> count = int(input('Количество ступенек: '))
Количество ступенек: 5
>>> print('\v'.join('_|' * count))
_
 |
  _
   |
    _
     |
      _
       |
        _
         |
```